# I cant install kali to virtual box using Ubuntu as host. I get this error:

Tags: virtualbox, kali

This is the error I get:

```
Failed to open the optical disk file /home/dan/Downloads/kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso.
Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/dan/Downloads/kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
DETAILS:

Result Code: 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: 
Medium
Interface: 
IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: 
IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: 
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Comment: My guess is that your iso is broken. Try re-download it and check checksum once done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `chmod 777 ~/Downloads/kalilinux-*.iso`

Comment: I tried redownloading it several times.  Someone suggested its a user right problem but didnt expand on it.

Comment: This is not an answer and has already been commented. Check iso checksum (it is not for nothing they provide checksum).

Comment: @Linuxuser001 run 'chmod 777 ~/Downloads/kali-linux*.iso' in terminal

Comment: Sorry about formatting (stupid iPad)

Comment: What is the terminal command for checksum and a link to compare the hash.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/downloads/

Comment: For sha1 simply run 'openssl dgst -sha1 somefile | grep -s "original hash from site"' if they are the same it will output the sum if not it will be blank

Comment: can I run md5sum command from terminal or is this only for ubuntu. Sory Im fairly new to linux and this is my first day using ASK.  All this info is very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: @Linuxuser001 you cannot use md5sum as these are sha1 sums but you can use sha1sum

Comment: This is what I got:     3dee064b758f0c22c61b6b73faa842e449ba7236

Comment: this is the checksum from beside where I downloded the iso.     2b8d2db20e2709c5e9e0f9f9bbd8606c9b9e729f

Comment: Im downloading again and will compare again.

Comment: I downloaded again and virtualbox excepted it .  When I use this command in terminal sha1sum I get this:dan@dan-OptiPlex-745:~/Downloads$ sha1sum kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64 (1).iso
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
I used sha1sum earlier on the other iso and it worked fine, but did not have brackets.  So what do I do?

Comment: If virtual box accepted it you are fine.

Comment: @Linuxuser001 you need to escape the space and parenteses instead try this: `sha1sum kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64\ \(1\).iso` But @Ron is right if Virtual Box accepted it you are most likely fine